# nodejs sequelize beforeCreate hook to do some validation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Before inserting a new record in the database I need to perform some checks and then decide if the record can be insterted or not.
I thought to use the beforeCreate hook doing something like this:

```
    Data.beforeCreate(function(object, options) {
        Data.scope('complexQuery').findAll().then(function (result) {
            if (result.length >= 1) {
// do not insert the record
            }
            else {
// go ahead and insert
            }
        });
    });
```

Any idea on how to stop the creation of the record?

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either throw an error, or reject the promise:

```
    Data.beforeCreate(function(object, options) {
        Data.scope('complexQuery').findAll().then(function (result) {
            if (result.length >= 1) {
                 throw new Error('Already exists')
                 return sequelize.Promise.reject('Already exists')
            }
            else {
// go ahead and insert
            }
        });
    });
```

Since you are actually doing validation, it would maybe fit better as a validation function :)

```
sequelize.define('model', attributes, {
    validate: {
        complexQuery: function () {
            // Do the validation here instead
        }
    }
});
```

The validation is run both for creates and updates

Comment: Is it possible to write separate validations for creates and updates in sequelize?